# htaccess forbid viewing directory but not the files under

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file in admin directory which has following code limiting access to specific ip address only. It works and show user access forbidden if user enter domain.com/admin/. However if the user enter domain.com/admin/home.php, then it bring up the page. How do I fix this?

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
<Limit GET>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Limit>
```

Tried looking up htaccess syntax and it is supposed to work as is. Don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: I think you can try `Options +Indexes`. However, because there is a `DirectoryIndex` entry, if `home.php` is not on the request, it will load it as the index. Try removing `DirectoryIndex` and adding `Options +Indexes`

Comment: Not sure why `/admin/home.php` should not also get a 403 response here, can't see what possible reason there could be for this. Why are you specifically limiting this to method GET though, especially in an admin section, I would expect a lot of POST requests as well. What happens when you simply remove the `<Limit>` wrapper around this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not just seeing a cached response? The directives you’ve posted would block such a request.

Comment: I have tried Options +Indexes. I have tried removing <Limit GET>
and </Limit> . Both did not fix. No I am not seeing cache response. I can remove Allow from with my ip address and test. If I have my ip in allow list, I can go either /admin or /admin/home.php without any 403 forbidden response. If I remove my ip, I get 403 response from /admin/ but I can still see admin/home.php. We moved our ecommerce site a new server and this started happening.  It is on CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 (Core). I am wondering if anything in apache config could cause something like this.

Comment: What Apache version are you on? What directives do you have in the parent config/`.htaccess` file? "We moved our ecommerce site a new server and this started happening." - You should have mentioned that in the question. It's quite likely that changes in the server config could affect this. For instance, if `.php` requests are now _proxied_ to the backend PHP engine then this may "bypass" your auth logic in userland `.htaccess` files. How is PHP implemented on your system? Apache module, FastCGI?

Comment: (_Aside:_ Btw, you don't want to set `Options +Indexes`, or remove the `DirectoryIndex` directive!? Not sure what the reasoning was behind that, when the "problem" would seem to be when the `home.php` file is requested directly. @user2182349)